# Resilient design of application that have a module that crashes randomly

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Question: How to design an java application around calls that hang randomly?

Situation: I have a java application which is in fact a series of selenium 2 tests using a Java API. And the application hangs regularly in:
    driver.findElement(By.id(string))

(If you know why this hangs could happen I will be delighted)

I want to kill that call when it hangs. How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't 'skip it when it hangs' - because it is hung.

you may be able to thread it and check on the thread.